# Understanding output of command: date -d "12:24 <lower-case-alphabet>"

Tags: command-line, time, date, coreutils

Can someone please help me understand why adding any lower-case-alphabet (a-z) as below makes a difference in date -d output and what do these letters in that command mean?

```
wip$ date -d "12:24 a"
Mon Apr 18 18:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 b"
Mon Apr 18 19:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 c"
Mon Apr 18 20:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 d"
Mon Apr 18 21:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 e"
Mon Apr 18 22:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 f"
Mon Apr 18 23:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 g"
Tue Apr 19 00:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 h"
Tue Apr 19 01:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 i"
Tue Apr 19 02:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 j"
date: invalid date ‘12:24 j’
wip$ date -d "12:24 k"
Tue Apr 19 03:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 l"
Tue Apr 19 04:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 m"
Tue Apr 19 05:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 n"
Mon Apr 18 16:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 o"
Mon Apr 18 15:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 p"
Mon Apr 18 14:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 q"
Mon Apr 18 13:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 r"
Mon Apr 18 12:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 s"
Mon Apr 18 11:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 t"
Mon Apr 18 10:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 u"
Mon Apr 18 09:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 v"
Mon Apr 18 08:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 w"
Mon Apr 18 07:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 x"
Mon Apr 18 06:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 y"
Mon Apr 18 05:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 z"
Mon Apr 18 17:54:00 IST 2022
```

man page didn't help.

I also found adding + or - before the alphabet gives same output.

```
wip$ date -d "12:24 -a"
Mon Apr 18 18:54:00 IST 2022
wip$ date -d "12:24 +a"
Mon Apr 18 18:54:00 IST 2022
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enabling debug output, we can tell that they're parsed as time zone specifiers:

```
% date -d "12:24 v" --debug
date: parsed time part: 12:24:00
date: parsed zone part: UTC-09
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (-09)
date: using specified time as starting value: '12:24:00'
date: using current date as starting value: '(Y-M-D) 2022-04-18'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2022-04-18 12:24:00 TZ=-09'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2022-04-18 12:24:00 TZ=-09' = 1650317040 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1650317040.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-04-18 21:24:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-04-19 06:24:00 (UTC+09)
```

Digging into the source code, these are specified in [`gnulib`'s date-time parsing code](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/3c99da63be95a3bc6cc881e1ca6c849a921569e1/lib/parse-datetime.y#L1156-L1183):

```c
/* Military time zone table.
   RFC 822 got these backwards, but RFC 5322 makes the incorrect
   treatment optional, so do them the right way here.
   Note 'T' is a special case, as it is used as the separator in ISO
   8601 date and time of day representation.  */
static table const military_table[] =
{
  { "A", tZONE,  HOUR ( 1) },
  [...]
  { "T", 'T',    0 },
  [...]
  { "Z", tZONE,  HOUR ( 0) },
  { NULL, 0, 0 }
};
```

They are [military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones). From Wikipedia:

> Military [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) are defined in the ACP 121(I) standard, which is used by the
> [armed forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armed_forces) for Australia, Canada, New Zealand, the United
> Kingdom, the United States, and many other nations. The names are
> identical to the [NATO phonetic
> alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet).
>
> Going east from the [prime
> meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Prime_meridian) at Greenwich, letters "Alpha" to "Mike" (skipping "J", see
> below) represent the 12 time zones with positive [UTC
> offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/UTC_offset) until
> reaching the [international Date
> Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line). Going west from Greenwich, letters
> "November" to "Yankee" represent zones with negative offsets.
>
> The letters are typically used in conjunction with [military time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_time).
> For example, 6:00 a.m. in zone
> [UTC−5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00)
> is written "0600R" and spoken "zero six hundred Romeo".

Comment: Wow.. This post can be anyone's benefit:
1. Try using verbose/debug options of commands to understand better (Silly I missed it)
2. For better understanding, look at the source code if once can (Again Silly me)
3. Various references and links online to understand why/how a feature was added
4. Most importantly, I haven't seen many better ways (template) of an answer on an online forum.

Comment: And yes, thanks to dev for adding military TZ, not confusing at all.

Comment: More documentation: `info date` to read the full manual. Also found online at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html -- particularly read the [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) section: it describes how date parses the user's input.

Comment: Indeed [it does](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-zone-items.html): "... ‘A’ has different meaning as a military time zone than as an obsolescent RFC 822 time zone"

Comment: Note that similar, but maybe closer to that obsolete RFC822, codes are used in Aviation.